# do actionscript 2 and actionscript 3 have a main class?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

Ive been reading a bit about actionscript 2 and actionscript 3, and there is something I want to ask, does these languages have a main class like in other languages ( C++ C#)...am asking this because I came across alot of code in the net and alot of them seem to not have a main class

Thanks

Comment: Not in actionscript 2.
In actionscript 3 there is something called a [Document Class](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/.../external_files_as3.html), but it's not the same thing.
A document class in actionscript 3 extends a Sprite or MovieClip which can be displayed on the screen, similar to a Java class that would extend Applet, if that helps at all .

Comment: it does actually, thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're technically wrong about your reply to George. AS2 does not have a main document class. It is POSSIBLE to create a type of pseudo main class, but this STILL requires some hackery by using code on the timeline to prototype the main SWF as a base object and add to it. This is not a document class, but rather a type of extension using flash prototyping. In AS3 you set the main document class explicitly as a compiler argument and that document class BECOMES the main object definition, as opposed to extending the existing one. Lets put it this way, if you asked Adobe if AS2 supported a document class, they would say no. If you stated that you use a document class in AS2 in an interview, they would tell you you're wrong and it would count against you. So the answer to your question is simply "no".

Comment: I think this answer would be a little more useful to the OP if you clearly described document classes and how they are established, with a follow up on how AS2 can be hacked. Just feeling like your answer, while correct, isn't very clear.

Comment: Thanks Bosworth I appreciate your reply. However, I've written this answer on the assumption that the person both understands prototyping (which should be a given if he/she was in the world of AS2 for a while) and inheritance (which should also be understood by anyone in any kind of OOP language like AS3). If anyone needs to understand these topics more clearly I think that a google search is more appropriate, since explaining basics of OOP and prototyping is a bit overkill for this question.

Comment: I think that Sam was replying directly to the end of of George's comment -- "if that helps at all." Meaning -- "yes Sam, it does actually help, thanks mate". I don't think that he was trying to say that AS2 actually did have a document class.